# Moto 360 won't vibrate with oneplus 3

Tags: oneplus-3, motorola-moto-360

I have a 1st gen Moto 360 and recently switched from a nexus 5 to a oneplus 3. My watch won't vibrate for new notifications or calls since then.

I did a factory reset and paired them again, didn't help. It buzzes when switch it off or on, so the hardware seems to be okay. I can't find any setting on the phone or in the android wear app that can affect this.

Versions:

- Nexus 5: Android 6.0.1 with up-to-date security pathes, I no longer have access to this phone
- Oneplus 3: OxygenOS 3.2.7
- Moto 360:

  - android wear: 1.4.0.2580363
  - google play services: 9.8.77 (560-135396225)
  - adroid os: 6.0.1

**Update**, after a few system updates and restarts it's back, but very weak compared to the time it was paired with the nexus5. OP3's vibrate is weak too, so that may be the cause.

Comment: Something to do with [Alert slider?](http://m.androidcentral.com/oneplus-has-absolutely-spoiled-me-every-android-should-have-alert-slider)?

Comment: @beeshyams I'm afraid not, it's in the lowest position (normal mode)